# Stop Rails client_side_validations from loading on /edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, client-side-validation

I have a form that admins partially pre-fill for their clients.

When the client logs in, they are required to fill in certain fields. Client_side_validations automatically highlights the empty fields in red, explaining that those fields ("cannot be blank").

That is normally the desired behavior, since the model is partially filled in, but in this case I don't want client_side_validations to trigger until after the user has in/out-focused from the field in question, or has attempted to save the incomplete form. How can I make sure the client_side_validations don't go off when the page loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can turn off client-side validations when your page loads, through javascript (using document.ready for example) and re-enable them again on focus in/ out

```
$(form).disableClientSideValidations();
```

and to enable:

```
$(form).enableClientSideValidations();
```

you can also call the `disableClientSideValidations` and `enableClientSideValidations` on separate input fields not the whole form

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change the architecture of your app, you can make complex validations to trigger depending on the action, but this will be a mess, you better start to use form objects, so you have your model and in other classes, form specific objects with there own validations.

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/activemodel-form-objects

Also you can use mixin modules to incorporate the validations in execution time when you want them, instead of have them hardcoded in the model.